# Locate and open remote files

Tags: emacs, locate, tramp

In emacs, the `locate` command provides a way to run unix's `locate` and open files on the local filesystem.

I'm using TRAMP to access remote files - is it possible to use emacs' `locate` to find and open remote files?

Answer (score 0):

Likely, it is not possible. `locate` uses `call-process`, which does not run remote processes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use Emacs's `locate` function with TRAMP per se, but you could connect to a host remotely and run `locate` on that system via `M-x shell` or `M-x eshell`. I have some wrapper functions which make this task easier (although I mostly got them [from](https://superuser.com/a/847528/361481) [elsewhere](https://github.com/howardabrams/dot-files/blob/master/emacs-eshell.org#shell-there)):

```
(defun remote-eshell (host)
  (interactive "sHost: ")
  (let ((default-directory (concat "/ssh:" (format "%s:" host))))
    (eshell host)))

(defun remote-shell (host)
  (interactive "sHost: ")
  (let ((default-directory (concat "/ssh:" (format "%s:" host))))
    (shell)))
```

After locating the desired files on the remote host, you can then open them via TRAMP using `C-x C-f /ssh:remotehost`

Also, if you're connecting via TRAMP to a remote host, you should make sure that said host is not sending any weird prompts since TRAMP doesn't handle those well. See more about that [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Frequently-Asked-Questions).